# mysql_query convert to PDO or mysqli looking for an example

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I have been crucified by many people for still using the old 'method' `mysql_query()` also I am in the process of launching my website which took me 4-months to complete and I would like to have maximum security for it.

So I thought now is probably the best time to get rid of the old habit and start using the new methods.

I have scanned over some tutorials but I have to admit it does seem rather (very) complicated compared to mysql_query()

The best way to learn is probably through example, so Im hoping someone would be kind enough to change the following example for me to a PDO and a MYSQLI statement so that I can see the difference between the two. If a brief explanation can be included it will be greatly appreciated...

Also what do you recommend is the easiest to learn? Mysqli or PDO

```
$sql="select * from Multiple_Picks where event_id = '$matchId' and
                  pick='$winner' and
                 abs(score-$winScore) = (select min(abs(score-$winScore)) from Multiple_Picks 
                 where pick = '$winner' );";    

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        //if(isset($row['member_nr'])){
            $winingMember = $row['member_nr'];
            $event = $row['event_id'];
            $pick = $row['pick'];
            $score = $row['score'];
            $tournament=$row['tournament'];
            $round=$row['round'];
}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: There are _millions_ of examples out there, just google for some! What question is not answered by those examples? Why do you need another one?

Comment: @arkascha I just thought an example from my code changed to PDO will make it a bit easier for me to grasp the concept, and then start of through the tutorials

Comment: Hm, that means quite a lot of work you expect us to invest to write your code. Why don't you read some "getting started" introduction instead and play around a bit yourself? This is not rocket science, and the basic tutorials do explain the basic concepts. Then, if you have some _specific_ question, then ask about that here.

Comment: To learn this I recommend learning from the Alex Garrett @ phpacademy on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEbKji_pSZM&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEbLm0ErHe7HgEOVIO26R_o

Comment: @arkascha fair point thats why im always very greatful for anyone giving any input to any question of mine...but I do get what you are saying

Comment: :-) we all are here to help, sure. And we all appreciate if people accept clear and open words :-) Thanks!

Comment: @arkascha just one question if I may...Would you recommend going the way of PDO or mysqli in terms of ease of use, I know many say PDO is more secure but would you say mysqli is easier to learn?

Comment: I don't see much difference in both. PDO does have advantages when it comes to abstraction, since you can use it with other sql servers beside mysql as too, so you gain in portability. But when it comes to security I would say that 99,999% of all security flaws are caused by the code implemented using one of both, not by the db layer itself. So it does not really matter what you choose, typically. The basic concepts are the same.

Comment: @arkascha point taken, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this helps you

using mysqli:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,$password,$dbname);

$fetch=mysqli_query($con,'select * from Multiple_Picks where event_id = '$matchId' and
                  pick='$winner' and
                 abs(score-$winScore) = (select min(abs(score-$winScore)) from Multiple_Picks 
                 where pick = '$winner' );');
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{   
        $winingMember = $row['member_nr'];
            $event = $row['event_id'];
            $pick = $row['pick'];
            $score = $row['score'];
            $tournament=$row['tournament'];
            $round=$row['round'];
}
```

using PDO

```
<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'username';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=animals", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database<br />';

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "select * from Multiple_Picks where event_id = '$matchId' and
                  pick='$winner' and
                 abs(score-$winScore) = (select min(abs(score-$winScore)) from Multiple_Picks 
                 where pick = '$winner' );";

    /*** fetch into an PDOStatement object ***/
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);

    /*** echo number of columns ***/
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /*** loop over the object directly ***/
    foreach($result as $key=>$val)
    {
    echo $key.' - '.$val.'<br />';
    }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: No! What sense is there in switching from the old mysql to the newer mysqli db layer if you do not take advantage of the additional features? This code smells of sql injection... Take a look at the benefits of "prepared statements" and "variable binding".

Comment: @Nikhil thank you this seems very similar to the old method..?